# iOS - CLLocation Manager didUpdateLocations being called in one class but not another?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location, foundation

Hi I'm making a program that gets the users location and puts an according annotation on the map. I started by writing all of the code in the View Controller and it gets the location perfectly. Below is the working code in the view controller.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    var userLocation: CLLocation?

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        determineCurrentLocation()

    }

    func determineCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       userLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        print("user latitude = \(userLocation?.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation?.coordinate.longitude)")
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (userLocation?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (userLocation?.coordinate.longitude)!)
        annotation.title = "You"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)


    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error \(error)")
    }
```

However now when I try and recreate almost the exact same code in another swift file. didUpdateLocations never gets called. locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() does get called.

Below is my new swift file which I call from the View Controller. Is there any simple concept I'm missing here because I really don't see why this doesn't work.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation


class SendLocation:  NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var userLocation: CLLocation?
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!

    func sendLocationPost() {

        determineCurrentLocation()
    }

    func determineCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        print("WHY")
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        userLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        print("user latitude = \(userLocation?.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation?.coordinate.longitude)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error \(error)")
    }
}
```

I call it using :

```
     let location = SendLocation()

    location.sendLocationPost()`
```

in my View Controller

Comment: Your instance of `SendLocation` is probably getting deallocated and its location manager is going with it.  Whatever class is creating your object needs to hold a reference to it in a property in the same way you are holding on to the location manager in a property.

Comment: That is exactly it, thank you! Never would have gotten that myself.

Comment: If the problem was trivially solved, might be good to delete the question.

Comment: just write the answer yourself, better not to close it...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are not keeping a reference to your SendLocation object.

Make SendLocation a property of your UIViewController.

For example, calling it from a static scope will not keep a reference.

WONT WORK:

```
static func sendLocation() {
    let location = SendLocation()
    location.sendLocationPost()
}
```

WILL WORK

```
let location = SendLocation()

func sendLocation() {
    location.sendLocationPost()
}
```